# App Crashes: Android Studio: Switching Activities Using If Statements (INTENT)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am creating an app that displays (x)/5, based on the output from the random number array. There are 5 variables in the array, that generate a number between 0 and 1. 0 is bad, 1 is good. If they get say 3/5, the activity switches to the appropriate activity.

```
12/24 20:28:53: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\sam\Downloads\OracleTheDeciscionMaker\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker/app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker.HomeScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 4122 on device emulator-5554
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker-2/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 21167(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 14(264KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 13MB/13MB, paused 3.199ms total 320.293ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2195(133KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(72KB) LOS objects, 23% free, 13MB/17MB, paused 3.735ms total 159.374ms
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
E/EGL_emulation: tid 4150: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb07fd4a0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
I/Choreographer: Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker, PID: 4122
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
                      at app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker.HomeScreen.onClick(HomeScreen.java:23)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

HomeScreen activity:

```
package app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        // Setting up an array of 5 random number generators between 0 and 1
        int[] guesser = new int[4];
        guesser[0] = (int) Math.random();
        guesser[1] = (int) Math.random();
        guesser[2] = (int) Math.random();
        guesser[3] = (int) Math.random();
        guesser[4] = (int) Math.random();

        // 0 out of 0
        if(guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, ZeroOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        // 1 out of 5
        else if(guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, OneOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //2 out of 5
        else if(guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, TwoOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //3 out of 5
        else if(guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 1
             || guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 0 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
             || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, ThreeOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity
        }
        //4 out of 5
        else if(   guesser[0] == 0 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 1
                || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 0 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 1
                || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 1 && guesser[4] == 0
                || guesser[0] == 1 && guesser[1] == 1 && guesser[2] == 1 && guesser[3] == 0 && guesser[4] == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FourOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // If this statement is true go to this activity

        }
        //5 out of 5
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FiveOfFive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array that only has 4 spaces, but then you try to assign 5 values:

```
// Setting up an array of 5 random number generators between 0 and 1
int[] guesser = new int[4]; // four spaces
guesser[0] = (int) Math.random(); 
guesser[1] = (int) Math.random();
guesser[2] = (int) Math.random();
guesser[3] = (int) Math.random();
guesser[4] = (int) Math.random(); // 5th value
```

Change it to this:

```
int[] guesser = new int[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should scan down the stacktrace error message and look for a line which has the name of a class and method which you wrote. When you do this, you will find:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
    at app.com.example.android.oraclethedeciscionmaker.HomeScreen.onClick(HomeScreen.java:23)
```

This tells you that the error occurs at line 23 of HomeScreen.java. Based on the error, this appears to be the line

```
guesser[4] = (int) Math.random();
```

If you look closely at the declaration for `guesser`, you have allocated 4 elements of the array. Java arrays start at index 0, so the maximum index you are allowed to use is 3. You can easily fix this by changing the declaration to create an array with 5 elements:

```
int[] guesser = new int[5];
```